# FQL Select recipients.Length = 2

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, select, facebook-fql

im searching and not getting this problem solved... i'm trying to get the reciptients with a FQL select where there is a conversations with 2 users like:

```
SELECT recipients, folder_id FROM thread WHERE folder_id = 0  and ({MeId} in recipients) and ({FriendId} in recipients) and recipients.Length = 2

SELECT recipients, folder_id FROM thread WHERE folder_id = 0  and ({MeId} in recipients) and ({FriendId} in recipients) and recipients.Count = 2
```

But i got always back all conversation thread with the users even if there are more then 2 persons

maybe Count or Length is not right, simple mistake? got no error, but the result is not what i suspect... hope someone can help

Answer (score 1):

FQL does not have a native `count` or `length` method. The only way to do this is return all the results and filter out the ones you don't want in your script.